# SQL Reporting : Permission error

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm configuring a SQL Reporting service. I think I'm missing something because:

Going on `http://my-ip-here/Reports/`
Logging with an user which is a domain user that I added to the Administrator group.

I add a freshly created user(it is activated, doesn't need to change password or something like that) as administrator:
[image]

Then I try to load the page on another browser, trying to log with IFT-SRV312\ReportingUser, but then I got this error:
[image]
(Sorry for the message in french, it has been installed in french :( ).

It basically means: "The user IFT-SRV312\ReportingUser does not have required permissions. Verify that sufficient permissions have been granted and Windows User Account Control (UAC) restrictions have been addressed."

What could I've done wrong?

Comment: Hope this link may help u http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlexpress/thread/9b5a8763-84ce-46d0-b011-067ad39223d1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my problem. In fact, in addition of the security parameters in website parameter, I've also to set some right(at least content browser) on the root folder!

[image]

Comment: This and a firewall rule to allow anyone on the network to access the service listening on port 80 worked brilliantly for me! In English the setting is 'Folder Settings'

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlexpress/thread/9b5a8763-84ce-46d0-b011-067ad39223d1

Also, see if "protected mode" is checked. If so, turn it off.

Comment: On which computer should I do this? The client? The server with reporting services? And with which account? I don't know what and where is the protected mode.